# Processing - mousePress image go to function

Tags: menu, processing, imagebutton, loadimage, mousepress

I have loaded and created two image buttons menuStart and menuExit withe menuStart.png and menuExit.png:

image(menuStart, 250, 350, 100, 42);

image(menuExit, 450, 345, 110, 45);

**What I've doing:**
I have set my pages as stages. stage 1 is a menu, stage 2 is a start screen stage 3 is a select difficulty screen + game, stage 4 is an exit screen, and stage 5 exits a game. I want to use the function mousePressed so that if the user selects the menuStart button in stage 1, stage = 2. Similarly if the user selects the menuExit button in stage 1, stage = 5.

**What I've done with code:** 
I have implemented the mousePressed but do not know how to set parameters for mousePressed in an image parameter. How do I go about setting this up?

code:

```java
void doMenu() {
  // Stage 1 Start -- MENU
  if (stage == 1) {
    textFont(title);
    text("Game", 150, 200);
    textFont(subtitle);
    image(menuStart, 250, 350, 100, 42);
    image(menuExit, 450, 345, 110, 45);
    mousePressed();

    if(mousePressed == true) {
      stage = 2;
    }
  }
  // Stage 2 START
  if (stage == 2) {
    background(255);
    startScreen = loadImage("start.png"); 
    image(startScreen, 0, 0, 800, 500);

    if(mousePressed == true) { // true -->start
      stage = 3; // go-to stage 3
    }
    /* else if(mousePressed == exit && stage != 2 { // exit
      stage = 5; // go-to exit
    }
    */
  }
  if(stage == 3) {
    background(255);
    startScreen = loadImage("start.png"); 
    image(startScreen, 0, 0, 800, 500);
    text("Press N for Normal or H for Hard", 200, 375);

    if(mousePressed == true) { // true --> hard
      hard = true;
      normal = false;
      startMenu = false;
    }
    /*
    else if(mousePressed == normal) { // normal
      hard = false;
      normal = true;
      startMenu = false;
    }
    */
    /*
    if(mousePressed == true) { // easy
      hard = false;
      normal = true;
      startMenu = false;
    }
    */
  }
  // Stage 4 EXIT
  if (stage == 4) { 
  background(0);
  exitScreen = loadImage("exit.jpg"); 
  image(exitScreen, 0, 0, 800, 400);
  textFont(subtitle);
  text("Press X to Exit", 300, 375);
  if(mousePressed == true) {
      stage = 5;
    }
  }
  if(stage == 5) {
    exit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mousePressed` variable does not work the way you're describing. It is simply a `boolean` variable that holds `true` when the mouse is being pressed and `false` when it's not. It does not contain any information about what's being clicked.

To check what's being clicked, you're going to have to use the `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables and `if` statements to check whether the cursor is inside the button. A simple example looks like this:

```
if(mouseX > buttonX && mouseX < buttonX + buttonWidth && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY + buttonHeight){
   //mouse is inside button
}
```

If the mouse is being pressed and the mouse is inside the button, then the button is bring pressed. You can use nested `if` statements to check this, or you could use the `mousePressed()` function:

```
void mousePressed(){
    if(mouseX > buttonX && mouseX < buttonX + buttonWidth && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY + buttonHeight){
       //mouse is clicking button
    }
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input) is a tutorial on getting use input in Processing.